# Drawing circles with specific radius size in 'RgoogleMaps' package

Tags: r, rgooglemaps

I am new to the RgoogleMaps package and I am trying to include circles to my map with an exact radius. Here is my current code:

```
library(RgoogleMaps)
data <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
                  dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")

lat <- data$Latitude
lon <- data$Longitude

PlotOnStaticMap(lat = lat, lon = lon, zoom = 10, maptype ="satellite",
                size = c(480, 480), cex = 0.2, pch = 19, col = "red", FUN = points, add = F)
```

Here for each "coordinate point", i.e. for each point on map comes from "data" dataframe with Latitude and Longitude information, I want to draw a 2 mile radius circle with the "coordinate point" as the center. So if I have 10 rows in data frame with Latitude and Longitude information, I want to draw 10 circles with each row as the center and 2 miles radius. Is it possible to do this? Is there a function for this in RgoogleMaps package? If not is there any other package available which I can do this?

I think of using left lower corner and right upper corner latitudes and longitudes ($BBOX$ll and $BBOX$ur) and combining this information with the size of the map  $size 480 480, to figure out what should be the cex value for a point with 2 miles. But I will really appreciate an easier method if there is one.

Thank you.

SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility (as long as the scale is such that a circle in the plot is close enough to a circle on the surface (not distorted much by the projection to a plane)) is to plot the circles using the `my.symbols` function in the TeachingDemos package.  Still use the RgoogleMaps package to download and plot the map, then figure out how far 2/10 miles is in terms of latitude or longitude for the region of the map.  Then you can use `my.symbols` with either the `xsize` or `ysize` argument set to the appropriate longitude or latitude (you can use the ms.polygon function with a large number of sides to approximate a circle).